# How do I give permission to app using CSOM?

Tags: workflow, permissions, designer-workflow, provider-hosted-app, app-permissions

I have a workflow in my subsite that is available when I activate a feature.
The workflow has app step and also the workflow running on my list at subsite updates a list on my root site.

To do so I need to give permissions to my workflow app identifier at the root site manually(from appinv.aspx and app identifier lookup value) and its app identifier appears when I see it in site app permissions at the root site.
Only then it allows me to update the list at my root site.

How do I do this using CSOM?

Below is the screenshot of what I am doing manually and want to do it using CSOM.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** CSOM API for granting app permission so far in SharePoint. A possible way is parsing the appinv.aspx page and submit the form in code ( Don't forget set the appropriate user-agent). I can provider a c# code snippet which works fine if you are interested.

Comment: can you please provide a code snippet to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible on On-premise using code ([parlaesolutions](http://parlaesolutions.com/blogs/Programmatically-Enable-Trust-for-Built-In-Workflow-App)). But I have not yet found a workable solution for SharePoint Online. I am Searching for it.

**Edit**:

Related question in stackexchange [how-to-retrust-an-app-programmatically-c-or-powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198131/how-to-retrust-an-app-programmatically-c-or-powershell)

Found this blog somewhat helpful [how-to-deploy-sharepoint-apps-with-vsts-release-management/](https://writeabout.net/2016/03/23/how-to-deploy-sharepoint-apps-with-vsts-release-management/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's 5.30am and my 2yr old son has just kicked me out of my bed, so there is a possibility that my brain isn't up to speed yet, but have you tried activating the feature "Workflows can use app permissions"?

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements... Instead of asking questions in answer section.

Comment: Since you must have 50 in rep to comment and I have of the time of this writing 36, please provide a workaround for that limitation and I will use it in the future..